# Convert a string to Double in C#

Tags: c#, string, double

I just wrote a method to convert a string to double. It does what it's suppose to do, but it seems too long and I'm thinking there's a better way of writing it. Please review and suggest a better way or point out why this is not good for production code.

```
     static double ConvertStringToDouble(string input, int rounding)
     {
         string[] split = input.Split('.');

         double wholeNumber = 0.0;
         if (split.Length > 0 && Int32.TryParse(split[0], out int temp))
             wholeNumber = (double)temp;

         double decimalNumber = 0.0;
         if (split.Length > 1)
         {
             string decimalString = (split[1].Length < rounding) ? split[1] : split[1].Substring(0, rounding);
             if (Int32.TryParse(decimalString, out int dec))
                 decimalNumber = (double)dec / Math.Pow(10, decimalString.Length);
         }

         return wholeNumber + decimalNumber;
     }
```

This is the updated method now. Thanks all for the contributions

```
   static double ConvertStringToDouble(string input, int rounding)
   {
       if (double.TryParse(input, out double value))
           return Math.Round(value, rounding);
       else return 0.0;
   }
```

Comment: This would likely be a better fit at: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What's wrong with just using `double.Parse` and `Math.Round`?

Comment: @juharr Almost always better to use TryParse imo, since it will handle values that are not able to be parsed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Net has built in functionality for this, its called [Double.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8). Double.Parse also exists, but its recommended to use the Try variant, as it won't throw exceptions if the number is not parseable into a double. You can use the method like this

```
string stringToParse = "1.7346"
if (Double.TryParse(stringToParse, out double parsedDouble))
{
  //do something with the double here
}
else
{
  //failed to parse, error logic here
}
```

Comment: I like this better.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use double.Parse and double.TryParse methods, I prefer to use them like this:

```
string myString = "1.05";

// This throws exception:
double myParsedDouble = double.Parse(myString);

// This gives you more control over the conversion:
double? myResult = null;
if (double.TryParse(myString, out double _myResult))
    myResult = _myResult;

if (myResult == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Not a valid double!");
}
```